# Assert that request verb is POST

Tags: php, request, http-verbs

How do you ensure early enough in the PHP request pipeline the verb is POST and deny others?

Comment: The earliest place to configure this would be in your webserver (presumably apache). It's incredibly trivial in apache, I think.

Comment: I wish @silky you make it an answer, not comment

Comment: @Col. I didn't make it an answer because I don't know exactly how to configure it in apache; if you figure it out feel free to post it as your own :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') die();
```

Comment: can't imagine post requests with empty $_POST? ;) a multipart with only file or text/XML for example

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: If you think that's funny you should check PHPoems, there was only really cool that had commands such as unzip, touch, sleep and so on - can't find it though. =(